# Check what file / software can cause a disk failure BSOD

Tags: hard-drive, bsod, hardware-failure

On Windows 7 64-bit HP (regularly updated) I'm getting sometime a BSOD saying that the OS can't read a system file and restart the PC. I have one SSD (OS and software) and two HDDs (with software and some temporary files).

How I can find the system file that went unreadable by the OS? Is there a specific log/dump to read?

PS: I know that I can try to run `chkdsk` or check for HD integrity with specific software, but I want to know which file causes the BSOD—if that's possible.

Comment: The BSOD tells you which system file is unreadable, so the software that is causing the BSOD, is the operating system itself.  You only need to resolve the system file integrity problem to resolve your BSOD problem.  You need to replace the HDD in question.

Comment: Run a disk check before throwing away what may be a perfectly serviceable HDD. The corruption may have been caused by a power glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I have is, you don't state what the BSOD error message actually is, so it may not be a corrupted file, it could be a bad memory location (faulty RAM) or even a faulty hard drive.

You could install some software like WhosCrashed and review the logs which are created on a BSOD.

You could install software like SpinRite to check the hard drive. May be even just a SMART tool like Acronis Disk Management will suffice.

You could run software like MemTest to check if the RAM is ok.

Comment: Thanks for WhoCrashed, that's what I was looking for. The strange fact is that usually when I got a disk failue the BSOD appear instantly, now the OS "starts to freeze": some opened apps got freezed, other still working and after a couple of minutes the BSOD appear.

Comment: PS: For the disk check I'm using seatools because I think that my second HDD is the freeze cause. But because I have also a crucial M4 and a WD green do you think SpinRite could check all 3 or do you suggest another?

Comment: Do you know what SpinRite is? If not, Google it and read up, I think that will help.

Comment: I've alredy searched for it and I've seen a "purchase now" that's wahy I asked it for another one :P By the way ok I'll give it a try.